# member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type in g.cs file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've already searched for a solution to this problem in StackOverflow but apparently this time is different.
In my Windows Phone application when the user presses a specific button the app  should redirect him to a specific Panorama Page so I followed this how to:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aschapiro/archive/2012/07/21/navigating-directly-to-a-specific-screen-inside-a-panorama-or-pivot-page.aspx

But when I compile the solution this error appears:

> 'donazione': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

But this error is in the .g.cs file o the donazione.xaml file created during the compilation, so I looked at it and the error is:

```
namespace Avis {


public partial class donazione : Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage {

    internal System.Windows.Controls.Grid LayoutRoot;

    internal Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Panorama donazione; <-- the error is in this line

    private bool _contentLoaded;

    /// <summary>
    /// InitializeComponent
    ....
```

Obviuously trying to modify this file wouldn't solve anything so here it is the donazione.xaml file which causes this error:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="Avis.donazione"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <controls:Panorama x:Name="donazione">

        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Il sangue">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item two-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Perché Donare">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Chi può donare">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Come donare">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Tipi di donazione">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="FAQ">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
    </controls:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

I confronted it with the how-to's ones but, except for the additional elements, the initial declarations are equal.

Anybody can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: The panorama control is given the same name as the page class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have a member in your class which is named like your class is.

Example :

```
class Test
{
    int Test; // error
    int Test1; // OK
}
```

**Solution** :

- change the name of `donazione` variable to something else.
- now since it is a .g.cs file you should do that from the design-view properties window

Answer (score 0):

If this is via the Main StoryBoard it is quite likely the same name has been typed into the View and View Controller (by mistake given the latency in the Main StoryBoard) - remove the name from the View