# What do I do to solve an enclosing type error?

Tags: c#

I have trying to create this code so that my player in Unity walks through a trigger box and sets off specific audio but when I put in this code it comes up with saying there's an Enclosing Error:

> [10:51:37] Assets/DoorFall.cs(7,24): error CS0542: 'DoorFall': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

I have tried changing different names and moved different nodes around but nothing is working.

```
public class DoorFall : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioSource DoorFall;

    // Use this for initializatoin
    void Start() {

        DoorFall = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision) {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "player")
        {

            DoorFall.play();

            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a variable named _DoorFall_ (the member) that is the same name of your class (the type). Change one or the other

Comment: Possible duplicate of [member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type in g.cs file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326569/member-names-cannot-be-the-same-as-their-enclosing-type-in-g-cs-file)

Answer (score 2):

Your class name `DoorFall` is the same as a member of the class `public AudioSource DoorFall`; name one differently.

Chances are you dont need the member to be `public` either.

```
public class DoorFall : MonoBehaviour {

    private AudioSource doorFallAudioSource;

    // Use this for initializatoin
    void Start() {

        doorFallAudioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision) {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "player")
        {

            doorFallAudioSource.play();

            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case [Compiler error CS0542](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0542) is being caused because the type name `DoorFall` is the same as the name of one of it's members (the public field). You should rename either the member or the type.

This generates a compile time error because the names conflict. Inside a method body in your type if you write or `DoorFall.[memberHere]` the compiler does not know whether to resolve the type or the member. Here is a more succinct example illustrating why this should generate a compile time error.

```
public class DoorFall {
  private static string ToString() { return "A"; }

  public AudioSource DoorFall = "B";

  void Start() {
    // what value would be assigned here?
    var result = DoorFall.ToString();
  }
}
```

---

On a side note it is almost never acceptable to declare a public field. Instead you should use properties to expose field values or to set them. If you want the value to be set/get publicly you could use an auto getter/setter.

```
public AudioSource DoorFall { get; set; }
```

If it never accessed from outside the type then declare it as `private` instead.